# SQL Server 2008, Powershell and Web Services

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Powershell provides the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet which allows for a web service proxy object to be created.

However the Powershell in SQL Server 2008 doesn't appear to support this. Is there a way to get SQL Server's Powershell to support the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. sqlps is minishell, where the only cmdlets implemented where those available in V1. New-WebServiceProxy was added in PowerShell V2. Note this does not mean sqlps is V1, rather the sqlps host implements a RunspaceConfiguration with explicitly defined cmdlets being the only cmdlets available in the host.

For a longer explanation [see my post on sqlps](http://sev17.com/2010/05/the-truth-about-sqlps-and-powershell-v2/).

You can of course use New-WebServiceProxy from the regular powershell.exe host.